Implementing Screen Streaming to RTMP in Flutter using Kotlin
I'm working on a Flutter project that requires screen streaming to an RTMP server. I'm using Kotlin Native for the Android-specific implementation and have integrated MediaProjection to capture the screen and stream it using RTMP.
I can't seem to properly manage the communication between Flutter and Kotlin Native for starting/stopping the screen capture and sending the RTMP stream.
Is there flutter package for screen capture with rtmp?
